# Docker: Web server not retrieving changes from mounted React app

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a simple React app that I want to link and serve from a Docker container while been able to edit in the host machine.

Image was built from the following Dockerfile, but never rebuilt since the idea is to test mounting and see changes automatically.

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . . 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I run containers with the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5001:3000 -v "$(get-location):/app" --name=binded react-app
```

I can verify that the "mounting" takes place because if I make a small change to my index.html and inspect the file from within the container with a parallel `exec` command while it's running, I get to see the updated version.

The problem is that when I access the app in the browser with `http://localhost:5001/`, I don't get the latest version. I get the version from the moment the container was `run`, and no changes are reflected after. If I run another container, I will get the latest version, but again only up to that point in time, not reflecting further updates to the file.

Btw, I'm editing the `<title>` tag for the sake of that test, and I'm refreshing the page myself (not talking about hot reloading).

So, where is the server running in the container retrieving the file from, then? And what do I do in order to always get the latest version of the app from the server?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need Docker for this use case.  Can you use Node directly on your host system, without introducing an isolation layer like Docker?

Comment: It's not a real development setup. It's a just a test for Docker capabilities, but this server behaviour got me thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved finally. The problem was that the server wasn't been automatically restarted due to nodemon not reacting to any changes in mounted files.

Solution was to run `nodemon` with argument `-L` to enable legacy-watch, after which it restarts with changes as expected.